# How to query nested associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

My models are
campaign.rb

```
has_many: views_logs
```

user.rb

```
has_many :views_logs
```

views_log.rb

```
belongs_to :campaign
belongs_to :user
```

I want to get `Campaign.first.views_logs.uniq.users.genders`
I know this query this is wrong but basically I want to get this

Comment: Not an answer, but as per naming conventions, `views_log` need to be changed to `view_log`.

Comment: Yes I know but I name it due to some reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the direct relationship with the through parameter:

```
class ModelName
  has_many :views_logs
  has_many :users through: :views_logs
end
```

Then you can query it like this: model_name.user.where(gender: 'male')

Comment: One thing I want to confirm if I delete or destroy campaign Either user deleted?

Comment: No, because we don't use the parameter `:dependent => :destroy`

Comment: I think it's not even possible through a :through relationship... but that's just an (educated) guess.

Comment: If you have another solution kindly give

Comment: For views_logs it works right.
But if I have same scenoario for likes then I cant know how to work